# How to allow more concurrent client connections with Netty?

Tags: concurrency, connection, client, netty

First, thanks all the Netty contributors for the great library. I have been happily using it for several weeks.

Recently, I started to load test my system but now I'm experiencing some scalability problem with Netty. I tried to fork as many simultaneous Netty clients as possible to connect to a Netty server. For small number of clients (<50), the system just works fine. However, for large number of clients (>100), I find the client side always prompts the "ClosedChannelException":

java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$1.operationComplete(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:157)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:381)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:367)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setSuccess(DefaultChannelFuture.java:316)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$ChannelCloseFuture.setClosed(AbstractChannel.java:351)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.setClosed(AbstractChannel.java:188)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.setClosed(NioSocketChannel.java:146)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.close(NioWorker.java:592)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.close(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:415)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.processConnectTimeout(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:379)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.run(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:299)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:44)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

I am wondering how to make Netty support more simultaneous client connections, such as 10K. I am using the newest version of Netty. Following is the testing scenario:

Each client sends a four letter string to the server and the server handler does nothing upon receiving the string. Each of the server and the clients is running on a high performance machine with eight-core and 16GB memory. The two machines are connected by a Gigabyte network.

Do you have any hints?

Comment: I see the following in the stacktrace '.processConnectTimeout' any reason why the client would timeout?

Comment: Perhaps the client boss thread is overloaded? I am not completed sure. But this problem disappears after taking Jestan's suggestion 3).

Answer (score 7):

1) You can tweak the connectTimeout in the client bootstrap to make sure there is no network/server issues

```
clientBootStrap.setOption("connectTimeoutMillis", optimumTimout);
```

2) By setting the backlog value in the Netty server, you can increase the queue of incoming connection size, so clients will have better chance of connecting to the server

```
serverBootStrap.setOption("backlog", 1000);
```

3) You have said that your application is creating many connections simultaneously, Client Boss thread [may lag behind](https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/70), if the application is connecting too fast.

Netty 3.2.7 Final allows to set more than one Client Boss thread in NioClientSocketChannelFactory constructor to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks Jestan. Your points are helpful. Indeed, it was because the clients were connecting too fast. After decreasing the speed of forking client threads, now Netty can easily support 10K concurrent clients without throwing any exception.