# Low concurrent connections allowed in netty

Tags: java, netty

I started to load test my system but now I'm experiencing some scalability problem with Netty. I tried to fork as many simultaneous Netty clients as possible to connect to a Netty server. For small number of clients (<50), the system just works fine. However, for large number of clients (>100), I find the client side always prompts the "ClosedChannelException".
Any clients above 100 will be disconnected. 
Where is my mistake? I'm sure than netty can handle thousands of connections.

I'm using netty 4.0.23

Here is my bootstrap and new channels settings.

```
public void run() throws Exception {
    int workerthreads = 10;
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(2); 
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(workerthreads);  //insert cashed sthread factory to constructor?
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap(); 
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1000)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class) 
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() { 
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {

                        //decrypt  //checknum
                        ch.config().setRecvByteBufAllocator(new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(2048));
                        //InboundDecryptor inbD = new InboundDecryptor();
                        //inbD.
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new InboundDecryptor());

                        //ping control
                        ch.pipeline().addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(Constants.getConnectTimeout(), 0, 0));
                        ch.pipeline().addLast("pingHandler", new PingOut());

                        //encrypt
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new MessageOutboundEncryptor());
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new ResponseHandler());
                        ch.pipeline().addLast("PackageHandler", new HandlePackets());

                    }
                })
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1000) 
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)

                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true) 
                .childOption(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 1000000);


        // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync(); 


        boolean exit = false;
        while (!exit) {

            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input;
            input = console.nextLine();

            if ("exit".equals(input)) {
                exit = true;
            }
        }
        f.channel().close();

    } finally {

        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        LOG.info("Server shuted down");
    }
}
```

I saw similar problem here:
[Other old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442166/how-to-allow-more-concurrent-client-connections-with-netty)

but none of the recommended solutions do not help.
I have set backlog and connection timeouts to high values, and my testing software create new connection only twice per second which must be far enough for boss thread to process them.
But still only 100 clients are allowed.

Comment: it's impossible to help without see the code etc.

Comment: Of course! I just gave the most important part in my opinion. What else do I need to show?

And by the way, netty is amazing. Thank you for it.

Comment: omg, what if problem not from netty side? I tested server using outer network, what if some network device prohibit more than 100 connections to single port. I need to test my server using localhost only.